# Multiple columns (one per type) vs. single TEXT/Clob column

Tags: sql, mysql, database, performance

I need to store some *diffs* of other tables' columns in the database. I want to use a single table.

### Option A

Table with 4 columns:

- `id`
- `content_type` (VARCHAR 255, will be: `datetime`, `integer`, `varchar`, `text`/`clob` ...)
- `old_content` (CLOB / TEXT, software serialized data for content-type)
- `new_content` (CLOB / TEXT, software serialized data for content-type)

### Option B

Table with ~10+ columns:

- `id`
- `content_type` (VARCHAR 255)
- `old_datetime` (DATETIME)
- `new_datetime` (DATETIME)
- `old_integer` (INTEGER)
- `new_integer` (INTEGER)
- `old_string` (VARCHAR 255)
- `new_string` (VARCHAR 255)
- `old_text` (CLOB / TEXT)
- `new_text` (CLOB / TEXT)
- ...

Only one tuple will be set at a time, the others will be `NULL`.

### Evaluation

At the moment I would prefer Option B - because I'm not a huge fan of serialized data in a RDBMS. However I don't know whether databases (in my case MySQL, maybe Postgre) would be better at handling (compressing) Option A in contrast to Option B.

I have seen approach B in some other projects (JBoss jBPM) and also feel more comfortable with B, but I'm ready to be lectured.

**Would you use A or B and why? What are the tradeoffs of each option? Or is there maybe a C?**

Other stuff that might be relevant:

- For the current project, I assume that there will be more data in the non-TEXT/CLOB columns.
- I do not want to search through the non-ID columns, so no additional Index is needed.

Answer (score 1):

Well, there is one more solution, more tables with supertype/subtype structure. The good thing about this one is that there are no extra nulls, for example:

```
TABLE DataChange (ID (PK), content_type, ChangeTime)
TABLE IntChange (ID (PK=FK), old_value int, new_value int)
TABLE StrChange (ID (PK=FK), old_value varchar(255), new_value varchar(255))
TABLE TxtChange (ID (PK=FK), old_value text, new_value text)
...
```

`IntChange`, `StrChange`, and `TxtChange` are types of `DataChange`, so `ID` serves as the primary and the foreign key and is the same number as the `ID` in the `DataChange` table. The `content_type` is the classifier column. **[Here is a model](http://www.damirsystems.com/?p=464)** of a similar (supertype/subtype) example.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a full response to your question, but take a look at "[Column Sets](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280521.aspx)" in SQL 2008. You can use it for OPTION A ... and make it look like OPTION B.